# How to replace pandas dataframe index values without using inplace and without canceling the index name?

Tags: python, pandas

It seems that all the methods found around use inplace but I read that it is discouraged.

Consider the following code

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "col1": [420, 380, 390],
  "col2": [50, 40, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index.name = "foo"
```

Next, imagine that later on I have to change the index values with these values `[0.0,0.1,0.2]`.

What I did is

```
df.index = [0.0,0.1,0.2]
```

but then `df.index.name` is empty (I expected `"foo"`).

I kinda understand why (you completely override the attribute `df.index`), but then I have no idea how to change only the index values while preserving the index name.

I want to achieve this goal without using `inplace`.

Comment: `df.index = pd.Index(new_index, name=df.index.name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the index by `pd.Index`

```
df.index = pd.Index([0.0,0.1,0.2],name='foo')
df
Out[91]: 
     col1  col2
foo            
0.0   420    50
0.1   380    40
0.2   390    45
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "col1": [420, 380, 390],
  "col2": [50, 40, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index.name = "foo"
df.index=df.index /10
```